# Is it true that $6|p^2 \implies 6|p$, where $p \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Is it true that $6|p^2 \implies 6|p$, where $p \in \mathbb{N}$

Where $6|p$ is read as 6 divides p.

I've tried finding a counter example, but I can't find one.

Comment: $6 = 2\cdot 3$, so $6\mid n$ if and only if ...?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If $p^2$ is a multiple of $2 \cdot 3$, then the prime factors of $p^2$ must include 2 and 3. Hence the prime factors of $p$ must include 2 and 3.